# String literals for array

Tags: c, string-literals

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char a[] = "125"; // (int)1, (int)2, (int)5. But array 'a' has a type char. So int is in char. ???
    printf("%s", a);
}
```

In that code, each element of string literal has type int. But the array `a` has type char.
In C99 6.4.5 $2 fragment
The same considerations apply to each element of the sequence in a character string
literal or a wide string literal as if it were in an integer character constant or a wide
character constant

In C99 6.4.5 $5 fragment
For character string literals, the array elements have
type char, and are initialized with the individual bytes of the multibyte character
sequence
I think they are not compatible, it's a contradiction to me. What's wrong about my thought?

Comment: "Each element of string literal has type int." -- That is the part where you are wrong. A *character* literal has type `int`. A *string* literal has type `char []`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is a string literal.

Quoting `C11`, chapter 6.4.5, String Literals:

> *A character string literal is a sequence of zero or more multibyte characters enclosed in double-quotes, as in "xyz".[...]*

To elaborate, the acceptable syntax for a string liteal is:

```
string-literal:
                 encoding-prefixopt " s-char-sequenceopt "
          encoding-prefix:
                 u8
                 u
                 U
                 L
          s-char-sequence:
                 s-char
                 s-char-sequence s-char
          s-char:
                 any member of the source character set except
                              the double-quote ", backslash \, or new-line character
                 escape-sequence
```

and then, the "source character set", referring (Chapter 5.2.1/P3)

```
Both the basic source and basic execution character sets shall have the following members: the 26 uppercase letters of the Latin alphabet

         A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M
         N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z
the 26 lowercase letters of the Latin alphabet
         a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m
         n   o   p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y   z
the 10 decimal digits
         0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
the following 29 graphic characters
         !   "   #   %   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   -   .   /   :
         ;   <   =   >   ?   [   \   ]   ^   _   {   |   }   ~
```

So, a construct like `"123"` is a string literal, not individual integers held by/in `char`.

Comment: Thanks, I misused the term character string literal. Then, in `char a[] = "xyz"`, does each of three elements('x', 'y', 'z') have type int according to the standard? Because "xyz" is a character string literal and integer character constant has type int. Standard says that `we regard  each element of sequence in a character string literal as if it were in an integer character constant`.

Comment: @opol `char a[] = "xyz";` is equivalent to `char a[] = { 'x', 'y', 'z', '\0' };` as long as x, y, and z are single-byte characters, and `'x'`, `'y'`,`'z'` and `'\0'` do have type `int`. It is OK to initialize a `char` with an `int` value as long as the value can be represented by the type. That's good because C has no constants of type `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`, `short` or `unsigned short`.

Answer (score 1):

```
char a[] = "125";
```

> In that code, each element of string literal has type int. But the array a has type char.

No, the fact that it's a `5` does not mean it has to be an `int`. The type of which has to be determined by the context of where/how it is declared.

In your case that `5` is of type `char` because it is part of the string literal.

Also note that `5` can be one of any other types such as `unsigned int`, `unsigned short`, `double`, etc. So again you must look at how it's declared in the first place.